# How to link_to index of another user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

In the goals **show page**:

```
<%= link_to goals_path, class: "btn" do %>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Goals
<% end %>
```

but instead of being taken to my own goals_path I want to be taken to the goals_path of whichever user's goal show page I'm looking at.

**goals_controller**

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished.order("deadline")
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.order("deadline")
    end
  end

  def show
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @goal
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @notable = @goal
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    @correct_user = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')
      @goal.conceal = true
      @goal.save
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    elsif
      @goal.save
      track_activity @goal
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Field: "Enter Goal"'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @goal.destroy
    redirect_to goals_url
  end

  def like
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    @goal_like = current_user.goal_likes.build(goal: @goal)
    if @goal_like.save
      @goal.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private
    def set_goal
      @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @goal = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @goal.nil?
    end

    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :like, :deadline, :accomplished, :tag_list, :comment, :private_submit)
    end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further **explanation or code** to help you help me :-]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a target user defined (or have a way to access a user's id), you can do something like:

```
<% link_to goals_path(user_id: @goal.user_id) do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Goals
<% end %>
```

Then you can modify your `index` method to handle a `user_id` param:

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  elsif params[:user_id]
    @goals = User.find(params[:user_id]).goals
  else
    @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished.order("deadline")
    @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.order("deadline")
  end
end
```

This should render a particular user's goals if their id is passed in as a param. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much Zoran that makes a lot of sense! I tried `link_to goals_path(user_id: @user.id)` amongst a few other variations but that gave me: `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` do you have any better alternatives?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com you need to have a reference to the user, i.e. `@user` needs to be given a value, or you need to use some other variable.

Comment: @Jon it has a reference. If I do rails console Goal.find(1) there shows a user_id attached to it: `user_id: 2,`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Jon's right - your `show` action doesn't have a user defined. You can try either defining it there, or substituting `@some_user` with `@goal.user_id`. I've updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry @Zoran that was one of the things I tried as well, but that just takes me back to the current_user's goals index same as before but now the url shows http://0.0.0.0:3000/goals.2 maybe I need to change the config file?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just take a completely different *route*, and be a little more REST-ful about grabbing `users/:user_id/goals`, and add it as a route in your `routes.rb`

```
   get "/users/:user_id/goals", to: "goals#user_goals", as: "user_goals"
```

and update your button to have

```
<% link_to user_goals_path(@goal_user) ... %>
```

and then add the `goals#user_goals` method

```
def user_goals
    @goals = Goal.find_by({user_id: params[:user_id]})
    render :index # or some other view
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I attempted your code giving me the error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Goals#show
No route matches {:action=>"user_goals", :controller=>"goals", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]`

Comment: Hmm... did you try `<% link_to user_goals_path(@goal.user_id) ... %>`

Comment: I put the method in the controller and the model. Not sure where. I also tried variations of this line as you also suggested: `<% link_to user_goals_path(@goal_user)` Maybe you can chat sometime to hammer this out real quick :)